# Translating Russian cursive to English

Tags: перевод

[image]

Hello everyone,

I am having trouble translating this note in Russian cursive. I have been able to make out a few words, but it doesn't make sense. Can someone please help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The writing says:

> Я думаю что важно знать русский язык потому что если это понимаешь, то знаешь что я хочу говорить

It's not written by a native Russian speaker and its meaning is quite obscure, but I think this is the gist of it:

> I think that knowing Russian is important, because if you can read this, you know what I want to say.

This is most probably a love letter of some kind.

Comment: This translation would be correct if the last word in the note were "сказать". However, the note says "говорить". A more accurate translation in this case would be "...you know that I want to talk".

Comment: @ANT: as I said, this is not something written by a native Russian speaker. The way it is put the writing makes little to no sense.

Comment: Maybe. But again, I offer this alternative version not because it is "more literal" or "more word-to-word". I offer it because it also makes sense. It is conceivable that the author of the note actually meant "...you know that I want to talk" specifically (as in "I want to keep our communication channels open"). Of course, we'll probably never know for sure.

Comment: @AnT No, the verb говорить is used in a different way "о чём я хочу говорить". You cannot say "что я хочу говорить" (unless the meaning is receiving pleasure from the procedure of saying, like some speech correction pattern).